# Nav bar sub menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, nav

I am having problems getting the sub menu on my nav bar to display correctly - hovering doesn't seem to be over the correct link ("media") but in between, and the dropdown displays off to the right and not under "media" link.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

HTML:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" title="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php" title="Find out more">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonials.php" title="What my students say">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a>Media</a>    
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.php" title="Get in contact">More Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

css here:

```
    nav ul {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the whole sublist ul inside the A tag, instead of after it. That means you need to adjust the nav ul li:hover > ul line as well (you can drop the > if you don't require further levels)